# Git Pulling commits reset in different machine

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull, git-reset

I had Commit A, B, C in my repo (A is the latest) which I am working on my office computer and private computer.

Then I reset commit A, B from my private computer and added new commit D. Now my private computer has commits D, C. Then I force pushed them so my remote repo also shows only D, C.

Now when I pull my repo from my office computer, it has commits D, A, B, C and a new 'merge conflict' commit that I had to do while pulling the repo?

How can I get my office computer to have same commits as the remote repo, (i.e. D, C)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull (`git pull`) means *fetch, then do a second command, usually merge:* that is, `git fetch` then `git merge`.  So the merge comes from the second Git command that `git pull` runs.

Since you don't *want* the merge, don't run `git merge`.  This means: *don't run `git pull`.*  Since `git pull` is really just *two* Git commands, run the first one yourself: `git fetch`.

Then, having obtained new commit `D`, you want to do the same kind of resetting that your force-push and your `git reset` did.  In this case, it means you will want to run:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

(or whatever the `origin/` remote-tracking name is, that corresponds to your current branch).  Be careful with `git reset --hard`, which erases any uncommitted work you have done: run `git status` first to make sure you don't have any such work, or are comfortable with discarding it.

(I recommend avoiding `git pull` in general.  If you *do* want a `git merge` after your `git fetch`, run that yourself.  But that's a separate issue.)

Comment: Great explanation, but it’s perfectly fine to use `git pull`. While it’s important to understand what `pull` means, it’s a useful shortcut for a common case. (Personally, I rarely use `fetch` by itself anyway, but YMMV.) I can’t see any benefit in avoiding the shortcut.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser: different people have different preferences, but I find that if people *learn* fetch first, then merge, they have a lot better understanding of what's going on; and in my case, if I *run* fetch first, this gives me a chance to look at what I might merge before I choose whether *to* merge (vs, say, rebase or do something else fancy), so I do this a lot.

Comment: That makes some sense. (I never rebase, so that particular choice is not one I find myself making...)

Answer (score 0):

Had to do

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

after `git pull`